# Lightroom processing question

Tags: lightroom, processing

[image]

How can I process a pic in Lightroom to look like this one ?[image]

That was pretty funny about the rectangle comments. I guess what I'm asking is I would like to replicate the feel of this picture. But I feel I mean the Rockwellian look to it. By Rockwellian if unfamiliar with Norman Rockwell I mean the color and text texture, lighting and the film feel of this picture. The way it is processed it evokes a bit of emotion and feeling it's not crisp and sharp but it feels a little bit more like film. I don't know how else to explain it it's a combination of the lighting the contrast the coloring the texture of the picture I'm trying to replicate that.

Comment: Use the adjustment brush: exposure as low as you can, then draw two rectangles. On a more serious note,: you should explain what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Please see this important information regarding asking "What's this effect?" types of questions. Until you can verbally articulate what it is about your example you want to replicate it's not a very useful question. http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions

Comment: That was pretty funny about the rectangle  comments. I guess what I'm asking is I would like to replicate the feel of this picture. But I feel I mean the Rockwellian look to it. By Rockwellian if unfamiliar with Norman Rockwell I mean the color and text texture, lighting and the film feel of this picture. The way it is processed it evokes a bit of emotion and feeling it's not crisp and sharp but it feels a little  bit more like film. I don't know how else to explain it it's a combination of the lighting the contrast the coloring the texture of the picture I'm trying to replicate that.

Comment: And I am not referring to the Santa magic. I am talking about the picture in its entirety without the glitter.

Comment: Can you post an image you are trying to achieve this effect with?

Comment: I'm trying To achieve this post processing in any picture. I don't think a raw pic as an example would help. A pic of 2 kids for example.  The pics as seen above are what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: The two example pictures look very different. The first one is a lot brighter and has much more contrast.

Comment: IMO, a Rockwell look is more about the subjects, decoration, and composition than it is the colors in the image.

Answer (score 1):

To preface; in my opinion, the two photographs are markedly different, except in subject matter. Also, everything I say here is purely subjective, as we don't have access to the exact process by which the photo was made.

However; the first photo appears to be slightly oversaturated, with the contrast increased. Also, if you look around the edges of the subjects, there's a bit of negative exposure there, from a negative exposure brush or from vignetting. Also, the sliders have probably been tweaked - increasing highlights, shadows, et cetera.

Similar to the concept of brushing negative exposure, one could also achieve a similar high-key color effect by brushing positive exposure.

Also, it appears that a pseudo-HDR effect has been introduced into the photo by the use of the 'clarity' slider (or 'structure' or whatever is similar) in the program that the photographer used.

In the second photo, it looks like either light painting or some positive exposure brushing has occurred, but it isn't a high-key photo like the first, and appears to have experienced far less editing.

As far as the sparkles... photoshop, or lightroom, or gimp, or whatever. That's not exactly a technically difficult effect to achieve.